# Java agent : transform() not invoked for all classes

Tags: transform, instrumentation

I have a very simple transformer:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtMethod;

//this class will be registered with instrumentation agent
public class PizzaTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {

    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, 
                            String className,
                            Class classBeingRedefined,
                            ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
                            byte[] classfileBuffer) throws 
    IllegalClassFormatException {
        byte[] byteCode = classfileBuffer;

        System.out.println("This class is  "+className);

        return byteCode;
        }
}
```

The agent code is as follows:

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class PizzaAgent {
    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
        System.out.println("Executing premain.........");
        inst.addTransformer(new PizzaTransformer(),true);
    }
}
```

The manifest is :

Boot-Class-Path: javassist.jar

Premain-Class: PizzaAgent

Can-Redefine-Classes: true

Can-Retransform-Classes: true

What is puzzling is only 4000+ classes were printed by the transform(), when 19000+ classes are reported as loaded by turning on -verbose:class with command line launching.

Why more than 10000 classes are not invoking transform()?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There may be two scenarios,

1. **Class yet not loaded by JVM**

   If any class yet not loaded by JVM, then there are chances that Java agent : transform() will not be invoked for that classes.

   Whenever it will be loaded by JVM Java agent : transform() will be invoked for that class.
2. **Class is loaded before initializing ClassFileTransformer**

   If you have used any class inside your ClassFileTransformer implementation or any other Agent class, then that class may be loaded before ClassFileTransformer initialization, so Java agent : transform() will not be invoked for that class

Answer (score 2):

You are only seeing classes that are not yet loaded when the agent is attached. If you want to handle loaded classes, too, you have to explicitly retransform these classes. You can do so by:

```
instrumentation.retransformClasses(instrumentation.getLoadedClasses());
```

However, some classes are not retransformable (`Instrumentation::isModifiable`) and you most likely need to split up the array to avoid draining your memory.

Comment: Thank for your answer.  But since I am using the premain way, isn't the agent added before any classes are loaded?  Aka, I am expecting no classes are loaded when the agent is attached.

Comment: Thank for your answer.  But since I am using the premain way, isn't the agent added before any classes are loaded?  Aka, I am expecting no classes are loaded when the agent is attached.  While I understand that some classes are not re-transformable, shouldn't application classes be re-transformable.  In any case, I was hoping that all of 19000+ classes invoke the transformer so I may check it with  Instrumentation::isModifiable.

Comment: Your agent is written in Java, therefore its classes and many system classes need to be loaded prior.

Comment: Yes! You are right.  It make sense that some classes such as system classes need to be loaded before the agent.

Still I am not seeing some application classes not invoking the transformer.  Do you have any suggestion as to the reason why this is so?

Thanks!

Comment: The JVM loads a subset of classes, like Object or Thread that are really required. Others, like HttpUrlConnection are loaded lazy.

Comment: I agree that some system classes are to be loaded prior premain.  However, isn't it right to say that all APPLICATION classes should invoke the transformer since they are loaded after main()

Comment: This very much depends on wheather you such classes from your agent, agent code is in no way special when it comes to class loading.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your last comment.  My simple code is not even performing any actual transformation.  Isn't the agent code loaded well before ALL application classes (because of the premain) and therefore ALL application classes will call/invoke transform()?  Consequently I expect ALL application classes to be printed with the println command.  This is how if run the whole thing:  java -javaagent:myAgent.jar -jar myApplication.jar.  Thks